# How to setup nginx to open index.html from certain folder

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I have installed nginx on the my server.
The nginx is working correctly, since I see a main page when I get to the my ip (let it be 1.2.3.4).

Now I want to build the React application and get possibility to deploy it via copying /build folder to the `/var/www/html` folder and open page via nginx server.

First of all I have to say I am going to provide a my most simplest attempt to avoid excessive information. So, I'll skip building steps and will stop on the simple index.html that I created in the `/var/www/html/my-site/build` folder:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Simple HTML Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
  <p>This is a simple HTML page.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

In the next I created `my-site.conf` in the `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`folder:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 1.2.3.4;

    root /var/www/html/my-site/build;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

That's all. Next steps:

- `sudo systemctl restart nginx`
- `sudo systemctl status nginx`

> Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor
> preset: enabled)    Active: active (running) since Mon 2023-07-10
> 18:59:08 UTC; 13min ago
> Docs: man:nginx(8)   Process: 11796 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5
> --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)   Process: 11810 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
> (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)   Process: 11799
> ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on;
> (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)  Main PID: 11811 (nginx)
> Tasks: 2 (limit: 2360)    CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
> ├─11811 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
> └─11815 nginx: worker process
>
> Jul 10 18:59:08 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-2gb-fra1-01 systemd[1]: Stopped A high
> performance web server and a reverse proxy server. Jul 10 18:59:08
> ubuntu-s-1vcpu-2gb-fra1-01 systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web
> server and a reverse proxy server... Jul 10 18:59:08
> ubuntu-s-1vcpu-2gb-fra1-01 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed to parse
> PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument Jul 10 18:59:08
> ubuntu-s-1vcpu-2gb-fra1-01 systemd[1]: Started A high performance web
> server and a reverse proxy server.

So, when I try to get http://1.2.3.4 from the browser I receive 404 error. More of then - I sure the nginx correctly read `my-site.conf`: when I am changing `try_files $uri/ =404;` to `try_files $uri/ =403;` I am receiving appropriate **Forbidden** error instead **Not found**

---

I followed 2 different tutorial and I haven't no more ideas what I did wrong. Please help.

---

Additional info:

After server (ngnix) started and I try to get 1.2.3.4 - I do not receive any new errors in the `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

- how to be sure where the nginx search `index.html` when I "ping" my server with GET method?